# Visual Studio 2012 Launches Wrong Project For Debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I've got an ASP.NET web application project in a Visual Studio 2012 solution. I'll refer to this as A.

**I copied A's directory to a new directory to make a clone of it. I'll refer to this as B.**

I made extensive changes to both A and B to the point that they are not even remotely similar. Stylesheets, scripts, HTML, and back end is all different.

I launched A for debugging, and it appeared in my browser as expected. I debugged the application for awhile, and then terminated debugging via the "stop debugging" icon on the toolbar within Visual Studio 2012.

I then launched B for debugging. Instead, I got A.

I tried clearing browser cache, though, this couldn't be the problem because the server side of the application was wrong too.

I tried Rebuilding the project, after running Clean. I still see A while trying to debug B.

I tried killing all processes related to the debugging session including all iisexpress.exe, MSBuild.exe, WebDev.WebServer40.EXE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe instances.

I tried closing Visual Studio 2012 completely, reopening it, and retrying debugging.

*EDIT*

After closing and reopening VS2012 for a third time, it started now allowing me to see B. Nothing else has changed.

---

Best I can come up with is there must be some type of project setting that needs to be changed to reflect that the project lives in a different space than it did before being copied, but I have yet to track down such a setting.

What am I missing?

Comment: Right-click project B node in Solution Explorer and set as "start-up project"?

Comment: @IrishChieftain I tried that, but it didn't work. Notice these are in two separate instances of Visual Studio - two separate solutions.

Comment: Go into properties/Web of each web app and make sure that they are set to run on different ports. If Auto-assign Port is selected, toggle to some port save and then toggle it back to auto.

Comment: @EugeneS. That's a good idea, and would probably solve the issue, but doesn't explain why this is happening. I'm killing all currently running instances of IISExpress. Why would running a new instance on the same port result in seeing the previous solution?

Comment: Can't you just set project folder in properties panel??

Comment: @johnyTee Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Press F4 to display properties panel if not displayed, than click on project in solution explorer. In properties panel there is a property called project folder which contains full path to project folder. I assume you can set the path there and correct project will always start.

Comment: @johnyTee I checked and the current path is set already.

Comment: Also, I have ran into problems like these if the `.suo` files are copied over. Delete the `.suo` for both solutions and report back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have just come across this issue today, having done exactly as you (copied a project, and then edited). And hence i would like to share my solution.

If you go to **Project B**'s `Properties` (found in solution Explorer), you will find a `Web` tab:

[image]

In your `Servers` section, alter the `Project Url` to:

`http://localhost:` + (number +1) + `/`

and then hit <kbd>Create Virtual Directory</kbd>

You should then be able to re-run your project and since they're running off different Url's, you shouldn't see this clash again.

Comment: This is actually the solution I ended up using as well - I forgot to come back and answer my own question. Thanks!

Comment: @crush: I'm just a few years late to the party :P

Comment: Had the same problem, and it took me forever to figure out what was going on. What's sad is that I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5... so this is still not fixed on their end. Sigh.

Comment: Ran into this on VS 2015 (Community), after creating a project template and then using it to create a new project, in the same solution as the original project. What's strange is the first time I ran without debugging it loaded the project fine, but later ran into this oddity.

Comment: Tip: if your solution has multiple pojects, you need to find your UI project and right click on that -> properties -> web

Answer (score 7):

I was in the exact same situation. The problem was that both projects (Project_A & Project_B) we’re setup to run on the same port in IIS Express.

IISExpress determines the port/application by looking at a configuration file located in <Documents>\IISExpress\config\application.config.

Open that file and look for a section <sites>. You should find a list of your VS projects. Locate your projects (A and B) and make sure that both projects are not running on the same port

```
<site name="Project_A" id="17">
<application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
<virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\Somefolder\ Project_A " />
</application>
<bindings>
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:64212:localhost" />
</bindings>
</site>
<site name="Project_B" id="18">
<application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
<virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\Somefolder\ Project_B " />
</application>
<bindings>
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:64212:localhost" />
</bindings>
</site>
```

If that is the case, remove one  entry (i.e. Project_B), and then go in Visual Studio to recreate the entry.

In VS, go in the Properties of Project_B. Click on Web tab and look for the “Servers” section.

Enter a new port (i.e.  `http://localhost:64213`) and click on the **“Create Virtual Directory”** button. This will add an entry in the “application.config” file, with the new association (i.e. Project_B / port 64213)

This should fix the problem. Hope this helps

Comment: This is another good solution. I'm not sure which solution is best. They seem to be roughly the same, but just done differently. I chose the other solution because it doesn't delve into manually manipulating the IIS Express instance config file (which I have done on occasion). I think it's usually best to allow VS to configure the file.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not marked as answered and as I had a similar problem I thought I would answer it.

you need to go to project > properties > web then check the use local web server box and overide application root if applicable, change the path names to the ones you are using save and it should work.